# How do I make a dataframe from two dictionaries based on matched keys

Tags: python

The idea is to make a pandas data frame with the following two dictionaries:

```
d1={('A','B'):{('C','D'),('E','F')},
    ('X','Z'):{('R','T')}}

d2={('A','B'):{('J','K')}}
```

The keys are IDs
Desired data frame output based on the matching keys:

```
Matched ID  | Value d1  | Value d2
('A','B') | ('C','D') | ('J','K') 
('A','B') | ('E','F') | ('J','K')
```

The ID ('X', 'Z') only exists in d1 but not d2 so it is not included in the desired output.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're going from your input to your desired output. If d1 and d2 have the same key, what are you trying to do?

Comment: It's not clear at all how your inputs lead to your putputs. Where does column b come from, why is `('J','K')` duplicated in column C

Comment: They are matched pairs based on the key ('A','B')

Comment: You should explain what the columns and the rows of the expected dataframe actually represent.

Comment: Inner join ,sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1, orient='index').unstack().droplevel(0).rename('B')
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d2, orient='index').unstack().droplevel(0).rename('C')

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner') \
       .rename_axis('A').reset_index()
print(df)

# Output
        A       B       C
0  (A, B)  (C, D)  (J, K)
1  (A, B)  (E, F)  (J, K)
```